# Drawing Circuits in LaTeX

Tags: tex-core, circuitikz

What package should I use to draw these circuits? [image: Circuit]

***Is it circuitikz?***

Comment: Yes, you should/could use circuitikz.

Comment: [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To provide you a circuitikz answer

```
\documentclass[8pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  (0,0) to[battery,l=$\SI{1}{\V}$] ++(0,4) -- ++(2,0) coordinate (1)
  to[R,l=$R_A$] ++(0,-4)
  (1) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,-2) to[R,l=$R_B$] ++(0,-2)
  (1) ++(2,0) -- ++(2,0) to[R,l=$R_C$] ++(0,-2) -- ++(-2,0)
  (0,0) -- ++(6,0) to[battery,l_=$\SI{2}{\V}$] ++(0,2)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Would produce something very close to this

[image: pic]